# External IP addresses for access control not getting set in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm facing a strange issue in Google Cloud SQL. I'm not able to set external IPs in access control. When I add a IP it shows updating when after sometime it does get updated.

[image]

But as soon as I refresh the page, the IP address is gone.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is connecting my local dev SQL Client to Google Cloud SQL, so I need to configure external IP address to give access. But It wasn't working and I'm getting following error

[image]

On further investigation I found that the IP I'm configuring is not getting updated as per error I mentioned above. Google Cloud SQL experts, please help.

Also, if I don't have static IP address of my own, what should I be configuring? I have got IPv4 assigned to my Cloud SQL instance.

PS: Not sure if it'll matter, but I'm under trial period of Google Cloud.

Comment: Could you try with 0.0.0.0/0 to allow access from every IP? 0.0.0/0 doesn't match any [CIDR block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Comment: Hi sorry that 0.0.0/0 was just sample I pasted in hurry, I tried with 0.0.0.0/0 and it too get removed once I refresh the page

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. Does it happen from the command line?
`gcloud sql instances patch INSTANCE --authorized-networks 0.0.0.0/0 --project PROJECT` 
You can find more information about this command at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/patch

Comment: Steps I followed are:

1. Login to [google console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select project
3. Select Cloud SQL
4. Select my Cloud SQL Instance
5. Click on Access Control
6. Click on Add Authorized Network
7. In the popup I entered 0.0.0.0/0 and saved it.

It got saved and I got message, but when I refresh the page again, it's gone

Comment: Could you post your project ID in a comment so I can create a ticket in Google Cloud Platform on your behalf? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by editing your Cloud SQL instance :
[image: Edit your instance]

Then you go directly to the Authorized Networks :

[image: Aloow your IPs]

And it should be ok.

Comment: This should marked as the correct answer. The other suggestions are mostly rubbish. This has nothing to do with passwords but is a simple bug in the web interface. Access controls added from the tab are not saved. You need to go to the Edit section as suggested by Ju. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a new password for your root user and add your ip address, then try again connecting with your MySQL client. This solution works for me.

Comment: I tried, and before refreshing I again tried to connect, getting the same error as mentioned above. Also on refresh, the IP address gets removed

Comment: try entering your actual IP address instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: ...and determine your IP address by visiting a site such as myipaddress.com to make sure it's your *externally visible* IP address that you're using...

Comment: I initially added all three IP addresses,the one I got from system IPv4, IPv6 and IP address I got from knowyourip.com ...... But I assume it's happening as these addresses are not getting saved actually, as when I refresh the page it's all gone